# Can't send post request with axios in React

Tags: excel, reactjs, axios, office-js, office-addins

I'm trying to make a post request to my back-end from my Excel addin using axios.post(), but the request won't go through for some reason. Although I am not sure, I suspect this has something to do with CORS or the fact that the request is being made from inside the addin in Excel.

Here's my code (not the real url for confidentiality reasons):

```
 const handleLogin = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const url = "https://myapiendpoint.com";
    const data = {
      email: email,
      password: password
    };

    axios
      .post(url, data)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status == 200) {
          // success
        } else if (apiResponse.status == 500) {
          // internal server error

        } else {
          // wrong credentials

        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  };
```

I am calling this function when the login form in my addin is submitted. The code seems fine to me, but the catch statement is executed every time the form is submitted.

What can I do about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the error message that is logged into the console in the catch block?

Comment: @Pavindu this is the error I get: ```ack":"createError@https://localhost:3000/taskpane.js:15975:24\nhandleError@https://localhost:3000/taskpane.js:15462:25","config":{"url":"https://myapiendpoint.com","method":"post","data":"{\"email\":\"example@email.com\",\"password\":\"example\"}","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1}}```

Answer (score 0):

As I thought, the problem seems to be that CORS blocks the requests made to my backend from within the addin. I have not fully confirmed this yet, but I have found a temporary solution that will allow me to continue to work on the addin.

So, I appended `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` to the start of the url in my request and the request does indeed go through correctly.
Needless to say, this solution is only temporary and should not be used in production, but it's an easy fix if you need to try something out.

Hope it helps!